# How to test only one input

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Here is my php code to check uploaded file:

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/header.php");

//=========================
//Check file upload
if (!empty($_FILES["file"])) {
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 524288000) {
            $mtype="error";
            $alertc="Image is too large<br/>\n";
            $labelc="labeler";
            $inputc="er";
        }
        else {
            $imgname = $arrusrselect[id].md5($arrusrselect[id]).$arrusrselect[id].".jpg";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/user/profile/" . $imgname);
            setcookie("success", "Profile picture updated<br/>");
            $labelc="label";
            $inputc="input";
            $upusers=$mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `img`='$imgname' WHERE `id`='$arrusrselect[id]'");
            $upimg=$mysqli->query("UPDATE `profile_img` SET `visibility`='$_POST[img_pub]' WHERE `id`='$arrusrselect[id]'");
            header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
    }
    else {
        $mtype="error";
        $alertc="Invalid file. Only image files are allowed<br/>\n";
        $labelc="labeler";
        $inputc="er";
    }
}
else {
    $inputc="input";
    $labelc="label";
if (isset($_POST['img_pub'])) {
    setcookie("success", "Profile picture visibility updated<br/>");
    $upimg=$mysqli->query("UPDATE `profile_img` SET `img`='$imgname', `visibility`='$_POST[img_pub]' WHERE `id`='$arrusrselect[id]'");
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
}
//check image visibility



//image check complete

//checking complete


$prof_img=$mysqli->query("SELECT `visibility` FROM `profile_img` WHERE `id`='$arrusrselect[id]'");
$prof_img_slct = mysqli_fetch_array($prof_img);
if (($prof_img_slct[visibility]) == "Public") {
    $imgchecka = "checked='checked'";
}
elseif (($prof_img_slct[visibility]) == "UsersOnly") {
    $imgcheckb = "checked='checked'";
}
else {
    $imgcheckc = "checked='checked'";
}

    if (isset($_COOKIE['success'])) {
        echo "<div id=\"msg\" class=\"success hide\">$_COOKIE[success]</div>\n";
        setcookie("success", "", time()-3600);
    }
    elseif (isset($mtype)) {
        echo "<div id=\"msg\" class=\"".$mtype."\">".$alerta.$alertb.$alertc.$alertd.$alerte."</div>\n";
    }

    echo "<form action='test.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>\n";
    echo "<table class='login'>\n";
    echo "<tr><td class='$labelc'>New Profile Picture:</td><td class='input'><input type='file' name='file' class='$inputc' id='file' /></td><td class='input'> <input type='radio' name='img_pub' value='Public' $imgchecka /> </td><td class='input'> <input type='radio' name='img_pub' value='UsersOnly' $imgcheckb /> </td><td class='input'> <input type='radio' name='img_pub' value='Hide' $imgcheckc/> </td></tr>\n";
    echo "<tr><td class='label'></td><td class='input'><p class='flag'> Max. size is 500kB. Allowed file types .jpg, .png &amp; .gif </p></td></tr>\n";
    echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' value='Update' /></td></tr>\n";
    echo "</table></form>\n";

include("includes/footer.php");
?>
```

What I want to is to change the visibility of the user image even if the user has not selected a file to upload. The alerts show up correctly when there is no file selected. But when I give a wrong file, (i.e. a .txt file for instance page still shows `"Profile picture visibility updated"` instead of the expected result `"Invalid file. Only image files are allowed"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to cast `(!empty($_FILES[file]))` with double quotes? `(!empty($_FILES["file"]))`

Comment: @MohdMoe Yup. But no luck! :(

Comment: oh are you sure you are echoing the error? try and add `exit($alertc);` **AFTER** `$alertc="Invalid file. Only image files are allowed";`

Comment: strange! do you have another code in file? and can you post your html code?

Comment: @MohdMoe Please check the edited code. The full php is there

Comment: i have posted an answer, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just tested your code, its messy and i dont believe it will really work, however your not getting the error message because of the following:

when the file is updated, you use `setcookie(..)` which I dont believe is the right way to achieve printing out the "success message", then you reload the page for the user so it loads directly to after `if $_FILES and if $_POST` check.

you then check if this cookie exist you print its value and then you try to unset this cookie, and at this point your code fails, because you CAN NOT send headers (setcookie, header(), session()) if anything is printed in the page.

now if you fixed that it would not work either, because you are submitting the image file and the image privacy `$_FILES and $_POST` both in the same request, so if `$_FILES` fails the `$_POST` request will succeed and it will reload the page and the error variables will be lost.

I dont know why would you use the `header("location:...")` function on upload success, you dont want the user to resubmit the data if he reloads the page? its not an issue and not even a security issue if it is for setting cookies with the success msg and displaying them, there are better ways.

i quickly tweaked your code, test if it works for you, and **NOTE** this is not the best way to do it the right way, im only providing you this so you can learn the basic structure for handling forms in PHP so you can (must) use them in functions and classes

```
<?php   
    /*  ADD THE PRIVACY TYPES INTO AN ARRAY,
        THE USER CAN CHANGE THE VALUE INTO
        SOMETHIING IS NOT IN YOUR CODE
        AND SEND IT TO DATABASE
    */
    $pubTypes = array(
        "Public" => 1,
        "UsersOnly" => 1,
        "Hide" => 1
    );
    #check if the submit button is clicked;
    if($_POST['Update']){
    #This (if) will check and update both file and privacy radio on each submit
        #the file validation and upload.
        #check if the file is not empty;
        if(!empty($_FILES["file"])) {
            $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
            $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
            if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
            #file type is allowed, continue and check size;
                if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 524288000) {
                    /*
                    $mtype="error";
                    $alertc="Image is too large<br/>\n";
                    $labelc="labeler";
                    $inputc="er";
                    */  
                    #set upload error/success to an array
                    $fileup = array(
                       "error" => 1,
                       "msg" => "Image is too large"
                    );
                }
                else {
                    #file size allowed upload the image and insert the values in the db
                    $imgname = md5(time() - rand(0,999))."-".$arrusrselect["id"].".".$extension;

                    #upload image and detect any error
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/user/profile/" . $imgname)){
                        #image uploaded successfuly
                        #update the data base
                        if($upusers=$mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `img`='{$imgname}' WHERE `id`='{$arrusrselect['id']}'")){
                            $fileup = array(
                               "success" => 1,
                               "msg" => "Profile picture updated."
                            );                         
                        }else{
                             $fileup = array(
                               "error" => 1,
                               "msg" => "Error updating the new picture value in the database."
                             );
                             #AT THIS POINT, you better delete the new image from server.
                             #@unlink("images/user/profile/" . $imgname);
                        }                       
                    }else{
                        #image upload ERROR
                        $fileup = array(
                           "error" => 1,
                           "msg" => "Error moving the file to the server."
                        );                        
                    }#endelse
                }#end if file size allowed
            }#end if if file type allowed
            else{
            #file type is not allowed
                $fileup = array(
                    "error" => 1,
                    "msg" => "Invalid file. Only image files are allowed"
                );  
            }
        }else{ #file IS EMPTY    
            /*NO need to print erros, because a user may
            only update his profile privacy only without
            submitting a new image*/
        }

        /* CHECK PROFILE PRIVACY UPDATE */
        if(!empty($pubTypes[$_POST['img_pub']])){
            #check if img_pub selected and its in a valid type, update the database.
            #you have to check the $imgname, because the upload may have returned errors.
            if($imgname){
                $sql = "UPDATE `profile_img` SET `img`='{$imgname}', `visibility`='{$_POST['img_pub']}' WHERE `id`='{$arrusrselect[id]}'";
            }else{
                $sql = "UPDATE `profile_img` SET `visibility`='{$_POST['img_pub']}' WHERE `id`='{$arrusrselect[id]}'";
            }
            #send the update query
            if($upimg=$mysqli->query($sql)){
                $pubup = array(
                   "success" => 1,
                   "msg" => "Profile picture visibility updated"
                );                             
            }else{
                $pubup = array(
                   "error" => 1,
                   "msg" => "Error updating picture visibility."
                ); 
            }

        }else{
            #invalid type, do nothing or you can reset the option to the default
            $pubup = array(
               "error" => 1,
               "msg" => "Invalid visibility type."
            ); 
        }
    }#end of $_POST['Update'];
    #END OF CHECKING IF THE FORM WAS POST;

    //get user's image and visibilty settings.
    $prof_img=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `profile_img` WHERE `id`='{$arrusrselect['id']}'");
    $prof_img_data = mysqli_fetch_array($prof_img);
    $vis = $prof_img_data['visibility'];
    if($pubTypes[$vis]) {$pubTypes[$vis] = 'checked';}
    #you can use the image in html
    $imgname = $prof_img_data['visibility'];

    # PRINT UPLOAD AND UPDATE RESULT IF ERROR OR SUCCESS
    #check file upload result, class will be class="file-error" OR class="file-success"
    if(is_array($fileup)){
        echo "<p class='file-{$fileup['result']}'>Image upload: {$fileup['msg']}</p>";
    }
    #check profile visibility result, class will be class="pub-error" OR class="pub-success"
    if(is_array($pubup)){
        echo "<p class='pub-{$pubup['result']}'>Visibility update: {$pubup['msg']}</p>";
    }        
?>
<form action='<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<table class='login'>
<tr>
<td class='<?php $fileup['error'] ? print("errorClass") : '';?>'>New Profile Picture:</td>
<td class='input'><input type='file' name='file' class='<?php $fileup['error'] ? print("er") : print("inputc");?>' id='file' /></td>
<?php foreach($pubTypes as $key=>$value){ 
echo "<td class='input'><input type='radio' name='img_pub' value='$key' value=".($value != 1 ? 'checked' :'')." /></td>";
}?>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='label'></td>
<td class='input'><p class='flag'> Max. size is 500kB. Allowed file types .jpg, .png &amp; .gif </p></td>
</tr>

<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='Update' value='Update' /></td></tr>
</table></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
$error = 1; // this flag will decide any error happens or not
if (!empty($_FILES["file"])) {
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 524288000) {
            $error = 0; // this error so make it 0
            $alertc="Image is too large<br/>\n";
        }
        else {
            $imgname = $arrusrselect[id].md5($arrusrselect[id]).$arrusrselect[id].".jpg";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../images/user/profile/" . $imgname);
            $upusers=$mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `img`='$imgname' WHERE `id`='$arrusrselect[id]'");
        }
    }
    else {
        $alertc="Invalid file. Only image files are allowed";
        $error = 0; // this error so make it 0 
    }
}
else {

}
//check image visibility

//If all well then, $error will be 1 otherwise 0 so in case of error like invalid file or file too large, following code doesn't execute.

if (isset($_POST[img_pub]) && $error) {
    $alertc="Profile picture visibility updated";
    $upimgvis=$mysqli->query("UPDATE `profile_img` SET `visibility`='$_POST[img_pub]' WHERE `id`='$arrusrselect[id]'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that `$alertc` is not set before doing your visibility update. You are also accessing array values in a deprecated manner `$_POST[key]` should be `$_POST['key']` you can surround the var in `{$_POST['key']}` when using `"` double quotes when defining the string.

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 524288000) {
            $alertc="Image is too large<br/>\n";
        }
        else {
            $imgname = $arrusrselect['id'].md5($arrusrselect['id']).$arrusrselect['id'].".jpg";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../images/user/profile/" . $imgname);
            $upusers = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `img`='$imgname' WHERE `id`='{$arrusrselect['id']}'");
        }
    }
    else {
        $alertc="Invalid file. Only image files are allowed";
    }
}

//check image visibility
if (isset($_POST['img_pub']) && !isset($alertc)) {
    $alertc="Profile picture visibility updated";
    $upimgvis=$mysqli->query("UPDATE `profile_img` SET `visibility`='{$_POST['img_pub']}' WHERE `id`='{$arrusrselect['id']}'");
}
//image check complete
?>
```